# Can't update data from sonarqube server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

When sonarlint eclipse ask me to refresh my sonarqube data (Update all projects binding), I get the following error :

```
Unable to update data from server 'cerbere' 
Unable to move C:\workspace neon\.sonarlint\work\cerbere\.sonartmp_1776998337301134698\4346381085123285128 
to C:\workspace neon\.sonarlint\storage\cerbere\global
```

As I also upgraded to latest version of sonarlint (2.1.0), I don't know if this caused my problem, that I hadn't had before.

I have to manually move the data to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect a problem with the whitespace in path.

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource You're right. After removing the space in path, the problem disappears. So I guess there is a bug in sonarlint actually ?

Answer (score 2):

As @Simon told me, it was a space in path problem.

Comment: I just had the same error message but with no space and no special char in my path. Then I tried again (without changing anything) and it worked. I guess the plugin isn't 100% stable.

Comment: I also suspect that some antivirus could have some kind of lock on the file preventing it to be moved else where.