# SonarLint: update all bindings issue

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

Updating all project bindings on the SonarQube server view (by right-clicking and selecting "Update all project bindings") gives the following error:

> Failed to update binding for 2 project(s)
>       Unable to update binding for project 'GRSP'
>       Unable to move C:\Users\Charlie\workspace.sonarlint\work\SonarQube.sonartmp_3019153116434277271\51596842470594041 to C:\Users\Charlie\workspace.sonarlint\storage\SonarQube\modules\HERMES
>       Unable to update binding for project 'HermesEtcs'
>       Unable to move C:\Users\Charlie\workspace.sonarlint\work\SonarQube.sonartmp_1777331285908263150\3707300483226920566 to C:\Users\Charlie\workspace.sonarlint\storage\SonarQube\modules\HermesEtcs

A similar question was asked here [Can't update data from sonarqube server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806365/cant-update-data-from-sonarqube-server) and the problem turned out to  be whitespaces in the path. The above paths don't have white spaces (I don't think), so not sure what the problem is.

I'm running SonarLint (version 2.6.0) connected to a SonarQube (version 6.2). 
Funnily enough, running SonarLint (version 2.2) does not come up with the same error.

Comment: Can you find a stack trace for this error in the 'Error Log' view?